# Hibernate @JoinColumn vs DB view performance wise

Tags: database, hibernate

I have `OneToMany` relation between 2 tables - `A` and `B`. I have 2 options.

*Option 1*:

Use Hibernate `JoinColumn` to retrieve the table `A` and list of data from table `B` using join.

*Option 2*:

Create DB view and select directly from the view.

I noticed in option 1 Hibernate will create `select` for table A and as many rows return it will create `select` from the table `B` with the join column condition.

What is the recommended option in this case *Option 1* or *Option 2* from performance wise?

Comment: Hibernate does a reasonable job of joining, and it’s less code. Also, a view is code, so you would have to manage that too. Unless there was some deep SQL Kung fu in the view, I would opt for the hibernate approach, because “performance” should include dev effectiveness, which means “less code”